# Parsing 'wresult' value without WSFederationAuthenticationModule

Tags: c#, wif, ws-federation, azure-acs

When returning from Azure ACS I retrieve a federation authentication result inside a FormCollection. The value containing the information I need is inside an encrypted value called "wresult". I'm having problems decrypting this value to use it for further authentication.

I don't want to use the WSFederationAuthenticationModule because I don't authorization cookies to be set. When the module is used, it'll automatically set auth-cookies with the Federated-Authenticationtype.

I instead want to retrieve the claims contained in the wresult and then set my own security token (be it JWT, SAML 2.0 or whatever).

The only possible workaround I found so far is to use the FAModule, and then delete the session token cookie right away. But this will result in the auth-cookies to be set twice in the response, with the value and right away unsetting it.

What I want to achieve in the end is the following:
Providing the possibility to either authenticate with a forms site, or authenticate using any identity provider in Azure ACS. Using the forms authentication I can compare the username and password right away and set the security token with whatever claims I want it to have. But when using Azure ACS, I want to compare the retrieve nameidentifier with saved values in my database first, and then set my custom security token, instead of the WS federation one. Or in case the nameidentifier is unknown, I want to redirect to a forms page where the user can authenticate this nameidentifier with his credentials. I don't want the azure ACS returned value to be calculated as authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to register the FAM - but you can still use its helper methods (e.g. GetSignInResponseMessage()) to parse the sign-in response message from ACS.

This gives you access to the protocol details and the returned security token without having to use the WIF cookie system.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying WSFederatedAuthenticationModule's default handling of cookies, I would suggest an alternative setup:

1. Create and host your own forms based auth identity provider STS. There are some [nice options](http://startersts.codeplex.com/) to help set this up.
2. Configure your new IP STS in ACS
3. Use the default ACS login page (home realm discovery page) or [customize your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185926.aspx).

Now your users will get asked to choose which identity provider they want to authenticate with. If they choose yours, upon entering a username/password, your IP will send a nameidentifier to ACS, which in turn sends it to your relying party website. Same goes if you add google as an identity provider. The benefit is your RP doesn't need to behave differently depending on what IP the user logged in from, but if you want to customize some behavior based on the IP, that information is available in the token issued by ACS.

Also, if you want to use JWT tokens instead of SAML, you can configure ACS to issue them from your relying party page in the ACS portal (though this is marked as beta functionality).

Comment: I don't see how this can help me. Directly on the first page I want the option to authenticate with my database password/username already, not HAVING TO choose an IP from my ACS. And how would I inject my custom claims immediately with other STS, like Live or Google?

Comment: Look at step #3. Your login page does not need to be an IP selector, you can make it whatever you like, such as including a database username/password login form. Also, you wouldn't inject custom claims immediately into tokens from other STSes, but you would configure rules in ACS to put claims in the token that you site gets from ACS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185955.aspx